# Symbols quoted in Scheme

Tags: clojure, scheme

I'm no Scheme expert so not sure if I'm using the correct terminology here. Let the code speak for itself:

```
CSI> (define tree '(1 2 3 'Symb 4 5 6))
#<unspecified>
CSI> tree
(1 2 3 (quote Symb) 4 5 6)
CSI> (symbol? 'Symb)
#t
CSI> (map symbol? tree)
(#f #f #f #f #f #f #f)
```

Coming from Clojure background, I thought symbols were used like this in Scheme, like keywords in Clojure. I'm supposed to go through a nested list structure and replace symbols with a function call. This is my onedimensional solution and it does work:

```
(define (print-track track attrs)
    (apply fmt #t
        (map (lambda (attr)
               (cond 
                     ((symbol? attr) (get-attr attr track))
                     (else           attr)))
             attrs)))
```

The empty space above the `(symbol?)` line was for a `(list?)` conditional, but it's likely the wrong aproach.

I'm using Chicken Scheme.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You've run into the Lisp quote "gotcha". In Scheme, symbols are used for variable reference, which you obviously understand. This evaluates to true:

```
> (symbol? 'Symb)
```

because you quoted the symbol, and prevented it from being used as a variable reference.

```
> (symbol? Symb)
```

Would first look up the value of the Symb variable, and then check if that value was a symbol.

```
> (let ((Symb 'foo)) (symbol? Symb))
```

Would evaluate to #t, since the value of Symb is a symbol: foo.

```
> (let ((Symb 7)) (symbol? Symb))
```

Would, of course, evaluate to #f.

You seem to have tripped on a nuance of quote.

```
'Symb
```

is actually shorthand; it's equivalent to

```
(quote Symbol)
```

which, again, returns its unevaluated argument.

But your code doesn't need the inner quote. When you

```
> (define tree '(1 2 3 'Symb 4 5 6))
```

the entire list is quoted; *nothing* inside of the list is going to be evaluated. That's why

```
> tree ; => (1 2 3 (quote Symb) 4 5 6)
```

Inside of the quoted list, 'Symb is equivalent to (quote Symb), which is actually a list. Since the whole list is quoted, using Symb unquoted would not be treated as a variable reference. It would just be the symbol.

```
> (define tree '(1 2 3 Symb 4 5 6))
> tree ; => (1 2 3 Symb 4 5 6)
```

Now, if you were passing all those arguments to the list function, what you originally did would be correct:

```
> (define tree (list 1 2 3 'Symb 4 5 6))
> tree ; => (1 2 3 Symb 4 5 6)
```

In that case, you're passing those arguments to a function; arguments to a function are evaluated, so you need quote to prevent symbols from being treated as variable references.

```
> (define tree (list 1 2 3 (quote Symb) 4 5 6))
```

Would do the same thing.